# Next page just adds more documents to page

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

Clicking on .next takes me to the next page, but all current documents will still show up – plus the new ones. None is taken away. So if page 1 shows a list of 4 docs, page 2 will show a list of 8 docs. Only a reload will show the correct amount (4) of documents. Why? Thanks!

```
displayQty = 4;
```

**Router**

```
var subs = new SubsManager();

Router.route('/browse/:page', {
    name: 'browse',
    template: 'browse',
    data: function() {
        subs.subscribe('PixPage', this.params.page);
    }
});
```

**Publish**

```
Meteor.publish('PixPage', function(page) {
    cursor = (displayQty * page) - displayQty;
    return MyPix.find({}, {sort: {uploadedAt: -1}, limit: displayQty, skip: cursor});
});
```

**Template**

```
Template.browse.events({
    'click .next': function(event, template) {
        var currentPage = Number(Router.current().params.page);
        var nextPage = currentPage + 1;
        Router.go('browse', {page: nextPage});
    }
})
```

Comment: could you please update this into a MeteorPad or update the current Github repo you gave on the other question

Comment: wild guess, subs manager caches the data, try with normal subscription `Meteor.subscribe('')`

Comment: @Ethaan I will update the [Githup repo](https://github.com/c6y/eboydb) later this night. :) This issue is solved though.

Comment: @Kai welcome, lets colse the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

subs manager caches the data, try with normal subscription `Meteor.subscribe('')`

Answer (score 1):

Always be specific regarding what data to display on your model.
Think of you're client as having a database that contains more data than you need to display, because often it does.

Use limit, order, etc in your mongo query to display only relevant data.